# Google Sheets IF Function using "one of many" values

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I'm trying to figure out a faster way to write this function:

**IF(X1=A1;B1:H1;IF(X1=A2;B2:H2;IF(X1=A3;B3:H3;** //*and so on up to* **If(X1=A400;B400:H400))))**

What I want is basically, if **X1 equals any value** from the **range A1:A400**, then I want the **corresponding row** inserted. For example, if **X1=A50** I want the **range B50:H50** inserted, If **X1=A199** I want the **range B199:H199** inserted and so on. Is there a way to achieve this without writing over 400 lines per hand?

Answer (score 0):

use this vlookup:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(X1; A:H; {2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8}; 0)))
```

Comment: While what you have written may answer the question, however it does seem a little lacking in [explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) and may illicit confusion to other users. Can you please expand upon your answer so that it is clearer and more accessible? This will make for better answers and help future users understand how the problem was solved.

Comment: Hi. Thanks this "kind of" worked for me, but the results are listed vertically, instead of horizontally. How do I fix this?

Comment: Actually, I found it. the Transpose function simply did it. :) Thanks